# How to install and run docker with nix

Tags: docker, daemon, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nix

I'm using Debian on WSL.
Nix is already install.

I install docker with this command:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.docker
```

I want to start the daemon :

```
systemctl start docker
```

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

**update**

FYI
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR= /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir
$UID=1000
$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS has no value

```
ls -l /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir
```

> drwx------  4 pierre pierre   120 Dec 26 00:41 runtime-dir

I can access the bus. But I need to use sudo

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Now I have this problem

> Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.

I think docker.service is this file:
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service

But it doesn't exist on my OS.
I'Ve tried to uninstall and reinstall docker with nix. To no avails

I think that it is linked:

https://discourse.nixos.org/t/docker-packages-systemd-unit-files-dont-work-on-ubuntu/12160

```
sudo cp ~/.nix-profile/etc/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/docker.service

sudo cp ~/.nix-profile/etc/systemd/system/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock

sudo systemctl enable docker


 Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.socket not found.
```

> Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.socket not found.

After reading this [link](https://www.lightnetics.com/topic/14552/how-do-i-list-all-available-system-sockets-on-a-linux-os), I use this command in order to the know where I should replace docker.socket file. :

```
 systemctl list-sockets --all
```

But no docker.socket is listed

**update

I have made all  the commands from scratch. Now I have this problem
A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you have to set your `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` manually (because `/run/user/...` is sometimes owned by some other user?? (Not quite sure to be honest)):

So can you try to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = "/run/user/$UID"` and then starting nix again?

If that doesn't work you maybe have to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` as well  to `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus"`.

You can find a similar thread to yours here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1561076/systemctl-user-failed-to-connect-to-bus-no-such-file-or-directory-debian-9

Did that help/fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must look for directory, use `cd ..` and go to `/bin/`, there is your program, then start use `./docker` or systemctl start docker.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo chgrp docker docker.sock
sudo systemctl start docker
```

No error message

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the default `docker.service`, for example, by changing the startup parameters

```bash
[Unit]
...
Requires=~/.nix-profile/etc/systemd/system/docker.socket

[Service]
...
ExecStart=/home/xx/.nix-profile/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

may be you need to reload

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```